# mongo query between two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
my Jobs is like below

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498f"),
    "jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
    "jobID" : "1",
    "companyName" : "xyz",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.xyz.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aba4c9bcdb5d4ae649197"),
    "jobProfile" : "Python Developer",
    "jobID" : "2",
    "companyName" : "abc",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.abc.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859000.0
}
```

and my Shortlistjobs collection is below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
    "jobID" : "1",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "applicantsCount" : 10
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6ababc9bcdb5d4ae6491f2"),
    "jobID" : "2",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "applicantsCount" : 8
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abac59bcdb5d4ae6491f8"),
    "jobID" : "3",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "applicantsCount" : 8
}
```

and i want all jobs which are present in Jobs collection with applicantscount from Shortlistjobs collection.only one field should be include from Shortlistjobs collection to Jobs collection douctment.

and i want output like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498f"),
    "jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
    "jobID" : "1",
    "companyName" : "xyz",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.xyz.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0,
 "applicantsCount" : 10
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aba4c9bcdb5d4ae649197"),
    "jobProfile" : "Python Developer",
    "jobID" : "2",
    "companyName" : "abc",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.abc.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859000.0,,
 "applicantsCount" : 8
}
```

i am using below query

```
db.Jobs.aggregate([
{ $match : {jobstatus:"Active"}},

{ $lookup:
 {
   from        : "Shortlistjobs",
   localField  : "jobID",
   foreignField: "jobID",
   as          : "meta"
 }
},

{
 $unwind: {
               path : "$meta"
           }
       },
        {
           $sort: {
             'meta.applicantsCount':-1
           }
       },{$limit:1}

])
```

following output i am getting form the above query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498f"),
    "jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
    "jobID" : "1",
    "companyName" : "IAAA Technologies",
    "jobCity" : "Bangalore",
    "jobCountry" : "India",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "iaaatech@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.iaaatech.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0,
    "meta" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
        "jobID" : "1",
        "jobstatus" : "Active",
        "applicantsCount" : 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-specific-fields-from-embedded-documents) to add specific field using([$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)) from the nested object along with all other required fields:

```
db.Jobs.aggregate([
{$lookup:{ from: 'Shortlistjobs ', localField: 'jobID', foreignField: "jobID", as: "meta"  }},
{$unwind: "$meta"}, 
{$addFields: { "applicantsCount": "$meta.applicantsCount"}}, 
{$project:{meta:0}}])
```

Comment: Is that what expected as you posted in your desired output?

Comment: you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/. This will allow you to preserve all  of the existing keys and add applicantsCount using $addFileds from the value derived from $project

Comment: "jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
    "jobID" : "1",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0,
    "meta" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
        "jobID" : "1",
        "jobstatus" : "Active",
        "applicantsCount" : 10
    },
    "jobAppcount" : 10

Comment: the above ouput along with some fields is coming then how can i remove meta object from resultant douctment